# Generating data from a High-Res. RGB image for a CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

Say I want to build a detection model that detects the existence of **X** or **NO X**.

The only piece of information I have, though, is a high res. RGB image, say 100k (width) x ~1000 pixels (height).

Let's also assume I cannot browse the internet to grab more data. I am stuck with this High resolution image. Can I somehow "slice" this image into multiple images and use said images as input data for my CNN?

How would I do so?

Comment: I don't think you could make out a lot from just one image....however you could try adding  some noise  to the one image you have with different intensities and try training your CNN with those....

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are really asking. Are you asking how to convert a high-resolution image to a low-resolution image?

Comment: Well no. Since we generally input images of around 200x200x1 (give or take) into CNNs, how would we generate extra data, from super high resolution images (i.e. in the MP range)? (that's if we can)